# Fill a DataFrame with values giving in a Map

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My objective is to create a function that taking a Map and a data frame as parameter:

> fillNa(columnsToFill, originalDF)

can fill the data frame with the values giving in a Map.

I'm working with a Data Frame similar to the one you can see below :

```
+---------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+
|seller_id|     nickname|successful_items|power_seller_status|
+---------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+
|260341211|HEBICOTE62617|              15|               null|
|269984665|VACAPERVIAJES|              12|               null|
|223499446|GAFAOCOSSR005|              10|               gold|
|265004480|NEFCOTEOC8179|            null|             silver|
|265200651|RUBENTARARIRA|              11|               null|
+---------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+
```

The desired output, therefore, is the following:

```
+---------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+
|seller_id|     nickname|successful_items|power_seller_status|
+---------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+
|260341211|HEBICOTE62617|              15|             normal|
|269984665|VACAPERVIAJES|              12|             normal|
|223499446|GAFAOCOSSR005|              10|               gold|
|265004480|NEFCOTEOC8179|               0|             silver|
|265200651|RUBENTARARIRA|              11|             normal|
+---------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+
```

The code that generate the DataFrame is the following:

```
val someData = Seq(
    Row("260341211", "HEBICOTE62617", 15,   null),
    Row("269984665", "VACAPERVIAJES", 12,   null),
    Row("223499446", "GAFAOCOSSR005", 10,   "gold"),
    Row("265004480", "NEFCOTEOC8179", null, "silver"),
    Row("265200651", "RUBENTARARIRA", 11,   null)
)

val someSchema = List(
  StructField("seller_id", StringType, true),
  StructField("nickname",   StringType, true),
  StructField("successful_items", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("power_seller_status",   StringType, true)
)

val originalDF = spark.createDataFrame(
  spark.sparkContext.parallelize(someData),
  StructType(someSchema)
)
```

However, when I tried to create a function that take an string and fill the values I can't do it for both fields. The best I could do is:

> 1- Replace only one column 
>   2- Duplicate the rows

The map using as parameter is the following:

```
 val columnsToFill = Map("power_seller_status" -> "normal",
                               "successful_items" -> "0")
```

The functions I've created:

Version 1

```
def fillNa_version1(replacements: Map[String, String], dataFrame: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
   dataFrame.na.fill(replacements.values.head, Seq(replacements.keys.head))
}
```

Version 2

```
 def fillNa_version2(replacements: Map[String, String], dataFrame: DataFrame)= {
  replacements.map{keyVal => dataFrame.na.fill(keyVal._2, Seq(keyVal._1))}.reduce(_.union(_))
 }
```

Comment: So if power_seller_status is null, you want to set it to "normal"?  Or am I over-simplifying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
originalDF.na.fill(columnsToFill).show()
```

yields:

```
+---------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+
|seller_id|     nickname|successful_items|power_seller_status|
+---------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+
|260341211|HEBICOTE62617|              15|             normal|
|269984665|VACAPERVIAJES|              12|             normal|
|223499446|GAFAOCOSSR005|              10|               gold|
|265004480|NEFCOTEOC8179|               0|             silver|
|265200651|RUBENTARARIRA|              11|             normal|
+---------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+
```

which appears to be what you want, no?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is replace your nulls with some sort of default value, there are much easier ways to do that.  You can use withColumn to derive a new column.

```
originalDF.select(
$"seller_id",
$"nickname",
$"successful_items",
$"power_seller_status").
withColumn("derived_successful_items", when($"successful_items".isNull,"0").otherwise($"successful_items")).
withColumn("derived_power_seller",when ($"power_seller_status".isNull,"normal").otherwise($"power_seller_status")).show
```

You could also use coalesce (returns the first non-null argument):

```
withColumn("coalesced_successful_items",coalesce($"successful_items",lit("0")))
```